# SQLite file won't persist from docker container to host

Tags: node.js, docker, sqlite, express, docker-compose

I have a small little node/express/sqlite application that I've docekerized and am using docker compose:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const SQLite = require('sqlite3');

// Create an instance of the Express app
const app = express();

// Create a Sequelize instance and connect to the SQLite database
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'database/database.sqlite',
});

// Define a User model
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

// Sync the User model with the database
sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database synchronized');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error synchronizing database:', error);
  });

  console.log('woo')
// Parse JSON request bodies
app.use(express.json());

// Define a route to create a user

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Fetch all users from the User model
    const users = await User.findAll();

    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch users' });
  }
});


app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Create a new user with the generated username
    const username = `username-${Math.random()}`;
    const user = await User.create({ username });

    res.status(201).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create user' });
  }
});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

```
FROM node:14

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port your application listens on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the application
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ~/database:/database
```

The problem I'm having is when I create a record in the users table it only is created in the docker container, but isn't persisted to the host.

How do I fix this?

**Ignore** I'm not able to post this because it's saying too much code even though I've leaned out the code as much as possible.

Comment: Shouldn't your container volume mount be `/app/database`?

Comment: Good eye. Also I fixed `- ~/database:/database ` to be `- ./database:/app/database`